# Why does calling a database function in a synchronous method called asynchronously require the DTC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr, msdtc

The full message:

> Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been
>   disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security
>   configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative
>   tool

This occurs after calling EndInvoke in the following code:

```
        log.Info("Getting dealer object for notifications");

        Classes.Dealership asyncDealer = new Classes.Dealership();
        Classes.AsyncLeadNotifier caller = new Classes.AsyncLeadNotifier(asyncDealer.AsyncSendLeadNotif);
        var threadId = 0;

        log.Info("Calling new notif methods");
        IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(dealerId, enquiryId, "new_lead", out threadId, null, null);

        log.Info("End invoke");

        // call caller.EndInvoke to wait until the process ends (important)
        returnValue = caller.EndInvoke(out threadId, result);


        log.Info("Notifications done ok");
```

The last line never gets called as an exception is caught.

The other relevant code is as follows:

```
public class Dealership
{
    internal static bool AsyncSendLeadNotification(long dealerId, long leadId, string notificationType, out int threadId)
    {
        var result = false;
        try
        {
            Hubs.LeadMessage message = new Hubs.LeadMessage()
            {
                NotificationType = notificationType,
                DealerId = dealerId,
                EnquiryId = leadId
            };

            // build a list of users we want to notify,
            // i.e. must be logged on and relevent to this dealer
            var responders = new List<string>();
            var connections = new List<string>();

            // NOTE: this could be reduced to a single query if performance becomes an issue
            // e.g. GetDealerResponderConnections

            log.Info("Getting list of connections");
            using (var context = new ReactDbEntities())
            {
                // get the responders we need to notify
                foreach (var row in context.GetDealerResponders((int)dealerId))
                {
                    responders.Add(row.Email);
                }
                // get current connections
                foreach (var row in context.GetCurrentConnections())
                {
                    if (responders.Contains(row.Email))
                    {
                        connections.Add(row.SignalRConnectionId);
                    }
                }
            }
            log.Info(string.Format("Calling Notify with {0} connection(s)", connections.Count));
            Hubs.NotificationHub.Notify(connections, message);
            result = true;
            threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return result;
    }
    internal bool AsyncSendLeadNotif(long dealerId, long leadId, string notificationType, out int threadId)
    {
        return Dealership.AsyncSendLeadNotification(dealerId, leadId, notificationType, out threadId);
    }
}
internal delegate bool AsyncLeadNotifier(long dealerId, long leadId, string notificationType, out int threadId);
```

> **UPDATE**
>
> The error seems to occur immediately after the "Getting list of
>   connections" log entry as the next log is the error. But I have no
>   idea why it would be using the DTC for an EF stored procedure call.
>   The DTC message only appears when calling the database from within
>   the synch/asynch code.

Bascially, it's an asynchronous method calling a synchronous method, which is why we need the faffing around.

The synchronous method gets a list of connections from the database and sends a notification to them.

This is the hub code:

```
    internal void Notification(string connectionId, string message, IHubContext context = null)
    {
        if(context==null) context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
        context.Clients.Client(connectionId).Notify(message);
    }

    internal static void Notify(List<string> connectionIds, INotifiable message)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
        using (var hubInstance = new NotificationHub())
        {
            var jsonMessage = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);
            foreach (var connectionId in connectionIds)
            {
                hubInstance.Notification(connectionId, jsonMessage, context);
            }
        }
    }
```

(Actually just typing this, I feel I could use more logging in the deeper methods, so I'll do that and update the question)

This works fine if I run it locally, just throws the error when running on the server.

As a point of interest, I had an error on my local SQL Server installation thats said my DTC had stopped and needed to be restarted.

I assumed that was something I did wrong but it does seem related.

Does this code need the DTC? What would be a better way to do it?

> [Edit]
>
> I think a solution may be to grab the list of connections before
>   calling the synchronous method and pass it in, IOC style.
>
> Will try that and update.
>
> [/Edit]

Comment: What does `GetDealerResponders` do?

Comment: Good question - it just returns a dataset. It doesn't call any server functions or anything like that.